# Yii Controller call from a View?

Tags: php, jquery, yii, yii-chtml

I have a view that has a form. I have a button which calls a controller via Ajax.

```
    echo CHtml::submitButton('Generate', array(
        'ajax'        => array(
            'type'    => 'POST',
            'url'     => CController::createUrl('Calculator/generateRetailers'),
            'update'  => '#div_retailers'
        )
    ));
```

The action controller what it does is to gather some data from MySQL and then renderPartial HTML tables into my form. Exactly in the `div` `#div_retailers`. This is the create option. Now I am trying to implement the update action which should render the information provided in the create action and draw the tables.

I would like to be able to call `generateRetailers` action controller from my view. Something like this:

```
<div id="div_retailers">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // I would like to call a url using jQuery?
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Calculator/generateRetailers"
    });
</script>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand your question/problem -- you seem to be showing how to call a controller action from a view (via Ajax). Can you clarify?

Comment: @ldg Yes! exactly I want to call a controller via Ajax from within a view. But from raw JavaScript with no buttons or links or any HTML object. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the exact same thing you already do in the widget:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // I would like to call a url using jQuery?
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo CController::createUrl('Calculator/generateRetailers');?>"
  });
</script>
```

Comment: now before making the call I need to call another JavaScript function. If I call JavaScript before the $.ajax, then the controller is not called. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: @ivan.freire: Depends on what function you are calling, how you are calling it, if it causes errors, etc. In any case, that sounds like a different question.

Comment: sorry definitely it is another question. Sorry, I had a JavaScript error, wrong index in an array. Anyway, your solution worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, there is no built-in url generator for ajax. So im calling ajax with helper variable, which is generated by my yii app. 
I use `Yii::app()->clientScript("config.url = ".Yii::app()->createUrl() . ");` 
and then in pure javascript i can use a global variable config where i have generated urls.

```
$.ajax({
url: config.url
});
```